# How to use legendCallback or similar when using Chart.js with TypeScript

Tags: chart.js

Today I have a working solution (using JavaScript) where I create a Chart (using Chart.js) and uses legendCallback to return html for the legend-part.
When I try to convert the code to TypeScript it looks like the legendCallback property isn't defined any longer.
Anyone can provide with a working example in TypeScript?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Maybe _you_ would like to provide _us_ with a working exemple of what you present, before expecting _us_ to provide _you_ a working exemple of something we may not fully yet understand? :) You may use something like CodePen or an other platform for hosting code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by importing a newer index.d.ts for chart.js